# apache2 and the magicial php binary

Tags: php, apache2

i updated and installed php to 5.2.11 yet 5.1.2 was still being used. I did a search of all php5 binaries and replaced it with a hardlink to php (which says 5.2.11 when writing -v). However, after doing a cold boot apache2 is still using 5.1.2. AFAIK i dont have any binaries left of 5.1.2 and my current json code doesnt run (in apache... does when i type php(5) code.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running php as an apache module then the binary will be different from the cli binary (it will be an apache module file). On my machine it is `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`, you might want to check that this (or equivalent) is up to date.